# Pine script is their is standalone compiler offline

Tags: python, pine-script, pine-script-v4

I have pine script and I would like to run them on multiple csv files, is their a way I can run them offline or standalone compiler or can i run multiple csv files all at one time.

Answer (score 0):

No sorry this is not currently a feature, although I would love this myself.

Cheers